# Bajo rendimiento de aplicaciones de 32 bits contra Azure SQL elastic pool

Tags: vb6, rendimiento, azure-sql

**¡Hola a la mejor comunidad de todos los tiempos!**

Estoy enfrentando algunos problemas de rendimiento con el grupo elástico de Azure SQL. ¡Gracias por leer!

La imagen ... estoy migrando a Azure nuestros sistemas. Parte de nuestro negocio principal está escrito en **aplicaciones de 32 bits**. Creíamos que el grupo elástico de Azure Sql sería una buena opción, pero el rendimiento **se reduce x3**. Creo que el problema es cómo estas aplicaciones de 32 bits negocian la conexión con la base de datos. También probé varios ODBC de MS y controladores de terceros. [El de Devart](https://www.devart.com/odbc/), por ejemplo. Sin éxito. XS

Escribo esto con la esperanza de que alguien haya tenido el mismo problema y **lo haya resuelto**. MS no nos brinda mucho apoyo y refactorizar el código no es una opción en este momento.

El recorrido consiste en instalar varias máquinas virtuales con servidores SQL y volver a migrar desde el grupo elástico. Pero eso llevaría más tiempo, incluida la replanificación.

Espero que se trate de configuración y / o de encontrar el controlador correcto...
Espero que este hilo te encuentre.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En Julio de este año (2021) terminé un experimento similar con una aplicación desarrollada en VB6. En mi caso utilicé el modelo de compra del Grupo elástico en `DTU` y el nivel de servicio más básico posible. Lo que encontré es que la respuesta de la base de datos para cada peticion es muy rápida, pero la aplicación creada hace más de 16 años no está diseñada para manejar de manera optima la interacción con `SQL`. En cada petición a la base de datos hay que sumar la **Latencia** y cuando esa latencia se multiplica por muchas peticiones, el tiempo de espera es significativo.

Comment: Es exactamente mi problema...